# use `lag()` to get previous timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, presto

I am trying to get first step timestamp to seconds step to calculate how much time it took  between two steps `post:/login_request`  and `post:/login` using `lag()` but it's taking timestamp each step and add it next record.

```
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
| device_serial  |  device_gen |   status_code |   method              |   event_time     |
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
| ABC345         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login_request  | 3/3/24 23:10:05  |
| ABC345         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login          | 3/3/24 23:10:10  |
| EFG456         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login_request  | 3/3/24 18:37:25  |
| EFG456         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login          | 3/3/24 18:37:28  |
| EFG456         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login_request  | 3/3/24 21:58:44  |
| EFG456         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login          | 3/3/24 21:58:48  |                                                                       
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

My Query and **[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qCUYJs5zdgzmnscXinnRd7/1)**:

```
select
    device_serial, 
    device_gen, 
    status_code, 
    method, 
    event_time,
    lag(event_time) over(partition by device_serial, status_code order by event_time) as first_step_ts
from test_tbl
```

what I am getting:

```
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
| device_serial  |  device_gen |   status_code |   method              |   event_time     | prev_ts         |
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
| ABC345         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login_request  | 3/3/24 23:10:05  |                 |
| ABC345         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login          | 3/3/24 23:10:10  | 3/3/24 23:10:05 |
| EFG456         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login_request  | 3/3/24 18:37:25  |                 |
| EFG456         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login          | 3/3/24 18:37:28  | 3/3/24 18:37:25 |
| EFG456         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login_request  | 3/3/24 21:58:44  | 3/3/24 18:37:28 |
| EFG456         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login          | 3/3/24 21:58:48  | 3/3/24 21:58:44 |
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

what I actually want:

```
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
| device_serial  |  device_gen |   status_code |   method              |   event_time     | prev_ts         |
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
| ABC345         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login_request  | 3/3/24 23:10:05  |                 |
| ABC345         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login          | 3/3/24 23:10:10  | 3/3/24 23:10:05 |
| EFG456         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login_request  | 3/3/24 18:37:25  |                 |
| EFG456         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login          | 3/3/24 18:37:28  | 3/3/24 18:37:25 |
| EFG456         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login_request  | 3/3/24 21:58:44  |                 |
| EFG456         |  i13        |  200          |  post:/login          | 3/3/24 21:58:48  | 3/3/24 21:58:44 |
*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
```

can anyone help to give me some guidane on how can I achieve above result.

Comment: Is there a guarantee that after a row with 'post:/login_request'  the next row (by time, for the same `(device_serial, status_code)`) will have 'post:/login'? Then nbk's answer does it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check methods  if it is 'post:/login_request' and set the result to NULL

```
select
    device_serial, 
    device_gen, 
    status_code, 
    methods, 
    event_time,
  CASE WHEN  methods = 'post:/login_request' THEN NULL ELSE 
    lag(event_time) over(partition by device_serial, status_code order by event_time) END as first_step_ts
from test_tbl
```

| device_serial | device_gen | status_code | methods | event_time | first_step_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC345 | i13 | 200 | post:/login_request | 3/3/24 23:10:05 | *null* |
| ABC345 | i13 | 200 | post:/login | 3/3/24 23:10:10 | 3/3/24 23:10:05 |
| EFG456 | i13 | 200 | post:/login_request | 3/3/24 18:37:25 | *null* |
| EFG456 | i13 | 200 | post:/login | 3/3/24 18:37:28 | 3/3/24 18:37:25 |
| EFG456 | i13 | 200 | post:/login_request | 3/3/24 21:58:44 | *null* |
| EFG456 | i13 | 200 | post:/login | 3/3/24 21:58:48 | 3/3/24 21:58:44 |

> ```
> SELECT 6
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IJNffpia)